# dbms_xmlgen.getxml - How to set a date format

Tags: xml, oracle10g, database

We are using dbms_xmlgen.getxml utility to generate xml using sql queries which fetches data from almost 10-15 related tables.

By default, date format is getting generated in `dd-MMM-yy` format. Is there any way we can set dateformat in dbms_xmlgen.getxml utility.

Notes -

1. It is not feasible to use alter session nls_date_format from oracle user who calls this procedure.
2. Also, We want to avoid using to_date function for each and every field since data is getting fetched from almost 10-15 related tables and it can degrade performance to use to_date for almost 50 date fields.
3. dbms_xmlgen.getxml was preferred as it is highly perfomant than other comparable packages.

Thanks.

Comment: to_char or to_date are your only options, besides you are using this functions in the select statement, the performance issue is not as representative as using them in the where clause. You can format the date field with to_char, example: to_char(dateField, 'yyyymmdd'), if you need a Date, you can apply to To_date after the to_char.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dbms\_xmlgen.getxml - How to set a date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256431/dbms-xmlgen-getxml-how-to-set-a-date-format)